# Laravel cron job

Tags: laravel, amazon-ec2, cron

I am not able to add my cronjob on amazon. When I sign in to my aws server. I run "crontab -e" command. When I tried to add my cronjob:

```
* * * * * php /var/www/html/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Its giving me error "E486: Pattern not found: var"

However, this entry is working fine on my local system.

Answer (score 1):

`E486: Pattern not found` is a `vi`/`vim` error. It seems that you're attempting to insert this line right after `crontab -e`, and that's incorrect way.

You should do this:

1. Run `crontab -e` — that will open vi/vim editor
2. Press <kbd>i</kbd> — that will enter editing mode
3. Paste mentioned line
4. Press <kbd>ESC</kbd> — that will leave editing mode
5. Press <kbd>:</kbd> (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>), then type `wq!` (force write + quit) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: i cannot find crontab -e where to put. please help me little

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
 * * * * * php /var/www/html/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

I hope this work for you...